# Process Builder and Flow

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

I have a process builder process that runs when an opportunity is created or edited and the opportunity stage is set to closed/won.   When this happens I am using process builder to create a NEW opportunity record.

Is it possible to get the ID of the new record so I can pass it into a flow?  It seems that I am able to get the ID of the record that started the process, but not the ID of the record created in the "Immediate Actions" "Create a Record" block of the process builder.  I am trying to get this ID as I want to use it in my flow further down stream.

Can this be done this way?

Comment: worse-case scenario... create the record in the flow as well and you'll have the id ;)

Comment: I believe you can not get the Id of the record that just got created within Process Builder. I would delegate the record creation to flow, it is much more versatile.